# How to cut a string CSV variable with unknown values count in bash, and loop over its values?

Tags: csv

It might seem very easy, but I'm stuck at this.

I have a string that is CSV and the length of items is unknown.

```
"item1,item2,item3,..."
```

I want to cut it, and loop over its items.

I tried:

```
while IFS=, read item;
do
   echo $item
done <<< $csvString
```

But it just gave me the entire string once.

And I can't use `cut` because I can't find how to loop over it.

Comment: Change `csvString` to `$csvString`

Comment: @EdgarMagallon, I updated the question. It was a typo. But it does not work.

Comment: Oh, I see. The problem is that the while loop actually reads line per line but the variable assignments consider the delimiter.  For example, if you had: `string1,string2,string3` and you se `while IFS=, read item item2; do ...` the values of `item` and `item2` will be `string1` and `string2,string3` respectively

Comment: @EdgarMagallon, yea, I know that. I can use `item1 item2`. But the length of parameters is not known beforehand. I don't know how many `itemX` there is in the string.

Comment: If you are using `bash`  use: `readarray -d ',' -t vals <<< "$csvString"`. That will create an array with a `N` number of items (according to the delimiter: `,`). You will be able to loop over the array

Answer (score 3):

You can't loop like you are showing because your input is a single line, and `read` reads a line at a time. The `read` operation reads the first and all subsequent fields into the single variable you provide.

If you want to process your input string item by item, you can do so by converting the items into the elements of an array and then iterating over these:

```bash
readarray -d , -t csvArray < <( printf '%s' "$csvString" )

for item in "${csvArray[@]}"; do
    printf '%s\n' "$item"
done
```

I'm using `printf` with `readarray` above to avoid adding a newline character at the end of the string (`<<<"$csvString"` would add a newline).

However, if your input string is a CSV string and not a simple list of comma-delimited substrings, then you can't rely on `readarray` to split your string correctly since some fields may contain embedded delimiters. You would instead use a CSV-aware tool, such as Miller (`mlr`), to parse the string and to perform whatever action it is that you want to do.

```bash
$ csvString='"1, 2, 3",Hello world,A,B,C'
$ mlr --csv -N put -q 'for (k,v in $*) { emit v }' <<<"$csvString"
"1, 2, 3"
Hello world
A
B
C
```

The above `mlr` command iterates over the single header-less CSV input record, outputting the value in each field as a new record.  Miller quotes the first emitted record automatically since it contains embedded commas.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `awk` as following (Assuming that `$csvString` contains strings of a Simple-csv format):

```
awk -v itmStr="$csvString" '
BEGIN{
       itmNr=split(itmStr, items, /,/)
       for (i=1; i<=itmNr; i++)
           print items[i]
}'
```